# Use DynamoDB item data with Amazon SQS in an AWS Lambda function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

OK so at this moment in time I have made an AWS Lambda function that takes in an object, translates the object to whatever language, and puts the translated object into DynamoDB.

What I need to do though, is set it up so when an item is put into DynamoDB, that sets a trigger to use the translation function using the data that was just put into DynamoDB. I'm aware I am supposed to use Amazon SQS but I really don't know how to go about it. I can't find any relevant help online.

I have made a queue and set it as a trigger to my function that puts the original object into the db, but thats all I have done. Can anyone help or even point me to the direction of a relevant tutorial or video?

Answer (score 0):

From [DynamoDB Streams and AWS Lambda Triggers - Amazon DynamoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.Lambda.html):

> Amazon DynamoDB is integrated with AWS Lambda so that you can create triggers—pieces of code that automatically respond to events in DynamoDB Streams. With triggers, you can build applications that react to data modifications in DynamoDB tables.

So, if you configure DynamoDB Streams for your DynamoDB table, it can trigger the Lambda function that performs the translation. There is no need to use an Amazon SQS queue.

Comment: When I put the item into the db though, I need to to run the translation function many times, once per language

Comment: DynamoDB Streams will trigger _one_ AWS Lambda function. That function, however, could trigger other functions. So, you could have DynamoDB Streams trigger a simple function that then calls multiple _translation functions_. Or, you could have the function push messages into SQS queues, but there's no obvious benefit to doing that.

Comment: Or have the function triggered by the DDB stream to put the message in SNS and have N translation functions subscribed to it.

Comment: You configure a Lambda function connected to a DynamoDB Stream. Once that Lambda runs, you grab its payload (which came from DynamoDB) and put it on SNS. Since SNS can have multiple subscribers, you then subscribe N Lambda functions to the SNS topic, where every Lambda L is responsible for a given translation T.

Comment: I agree. This is a good way to "fan-out" to multiple Lambda executions. Or, you could just do multiple translations in the same Lambda function since it is probably quick (especially with Amazon Translate).